# trouble installing opencv 2.4.10, python 2.7.5 on win7

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

i tried to install python-numpy-opencv as described in opencv official tutorial, but i have some issues regarding opencv -.-

http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_setup/py_setup_in_windows/py_setup_in_windows.html

so, python (2.7.5) and numpy (1.7.1) are installed (i imported numpy and it worked), then i copied that cv2.pyd from  C:\opencv\build\python\2.7\x86 and pasted it to C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages.

i tried to import cv2 but it wont work...

interpreter shows this error: module compiled against api version 9 but this version of numpy is 7

do you have any idea what is happening here? opencv version is 2.4.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [NumPy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NumPy) 1.9. Get an installer [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy) and an [OpenCV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCV) installer [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv).

There are lots of other cool Python module installers for Windows on that page; feel free to look around. It's kept quite up-to-date, and NumPy is compiled against the Intel [Math Kernel Library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Math_Kernel_Library) (MKL) for enhanced performance.

Comment: it works, thanks a lot.. i tried multiple combinations of versions and i got lost.. :)